# Separate Addthis js file

Tags: javascript, addthis

I would like to add a separate AddThis JS file

Currently it using its own CDN link:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=xxx"></script>
```

I tried to copy all the code and make my own `addthis.js` file but it didn't work.

I also tried the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="addthis.js#pubid=xxx"></script>
```

But I didn't work.

Can someone tell me how do fix it?

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately, the addthis_widet.js code isn't meant to be hosted by websites.  We reference other JS files which are hosted on our CDN, but since they are relative to the addthis_widget.js file, we won't be able to load them.  Also, we update the addthis_widget.js to reference updated files with fixes and new features, so if you try to host it yourself, you won't get updates.  Is there a reason why you want host the file yourself?